# ORACLE SEQUENCE using JOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

i'm trying to get nextval on Oracle Sequence using JOOQ.

so far i got:

```
create.nextval("SEQ_DATA");
```

The Sequence SEQ_DATA exist. I've check using:

```
select SEQ_DATA.nextval FROM dual;
```

and i got reponse.

The failure that i got are:

```
JOOQ; Bad SQl grammar [select "SEQ_DATA".nextval from dual]; nexted exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289
```

Did i miss something?

Regards,

Codescratch

Comment: That error corresponts to "Sequence does not exist", so you probably missed creating that sequence somewhere.

Comment: Is that a typo in your error message, or did you rename the sequence, but not regenerate the jOOQ code?

Comment: Oh, actually, @LukasEder is right, error says "SEQ_DA**D**A".

Comment: Actually i miss type on here StackOverflow. On the source code i type it right and SEQ_DATA exist and granted to the user. I can use select on the SEQUENCE